# Wireguard windows peer RDP works but nothing else

Tags: wireguard

i have a star topology wireguard setup:

[image]

Host A is running a web service [Xampp] for testing

1. ping from Host B to A ping 10.0.0.5 - OK
2. ping from Host A to B ping 10.0.0.4 - OK
3. ping from Host B to A to local LAN interface ping 192.168.1.100 - NOK
4. ping from Host A to B to local LAN interface ping 192.168.0.20 - NOK
5. RDP from Host B to Host A through 10.0.0.5 works perfectly - ok
6. http://10.0.0.5 doesn't work from Host B to Host A - NOK

Host A

```
netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface "wireguard" mtu=1280 store=persistent
```

Host B

```
netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface "wireguard" mtu=1280 store=persistent
```

No way to reach LAN interfaces ( LAN subnet )

My configuration files:

Server

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = 
ListenPort = 6543
DNS = 8.8.8.8
PreUp = sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT


[Peer]
PublicKey = 
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.5/32
AllowedIPs = 192.168.1.100/32    


[Peer]
PublicKey = 
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.4/32
AllowedIPs = 192.168.0.20/32
```

Host A

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = 
Address = 10.0.0.5/32
DNS = 8.8.8.8

[Peer]
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.0/29, 192.168.1.100/32, 192.168.0.20/32, 0.0.0.0/1
Endpoint = cloud-wg-server:6543
```

Host B

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = 
Address = 10.0.0.4/32
DNS = 8.8.8.8

[Peer]

AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.0/29, 192.168.1.100/32, 192.168.0.20/32, 0.0.0.0/1
Endpoint = cloud-wg-server:6543
```

Comment: What's the cofigured MTU?

Comment: Hello @vidarlo 9122 MTU for wg interface & 9202 MTU for LAN interface on Host B

Comment: Are you trying to run jumbo frames over the internet?

Comment: No, i've never look into this value, could be the cause?